# How can I apply JavaScript function to several different elements under the same class (with different results)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, padding

I'm using the padding-bottom trick to define the height of an element to prevent reflow. Typically I'd do this manually but since I have hundreds of images in my gallery it's best to resort to JavaScript. Now I believe I'm 80% there, I just need to refine the function so that I can get different results for all the different elements, since each image has a different ratio. Check out the snippet:

```js
(function () {

    var tags = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
    var img = document.getElementById('myImg');

    var width = img.naturalWidth;
    var height = img.naturalHeight;


    for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; ++i) {
        tags[i].style.paddingBottom = (100 * (height / width)) + '%';
    }

}());
```

```css
.item-box {

    display: inline-block;

    width: 30%;

}

.item {

    position: relative;

    display: block;

    border: 1px solid red;

    margin: 0;

}

.item img {

    position: absolute;

    display: block;

    top: 0;

    left: 0;

    width: 100%;

    height: 100%;

}
```

```html
<div class="item-box"> <a class="item"> 
    <img id="myImg" alt="600x400" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-600-400-1.jpg"/>
  </a>

</div>
<div class="item-box"> <a class="item">
    <img id="myImg" alt="600x900" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/transport-h-c-600-900-10.jpg"/>
  </a>

</div>
<div class="item-box"> <a class="item">
    <img id="myImg" alt="600x600" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/sports-q-c-600-600-10.jpg"/>
  </a>

</div>
```

I know that ID is unique to one element, but I can't figure out another way to get around this. Image 1 looks fine, but it's applying the same padding from Image1(landscape) to Image2(should be portrait) and Image3(should be square). Any advice as to how I can get around this? Thanks!

Comment: If you're getting all elements with class *item* as a collection, you can get each one's contained *img* using `tags[i].getElementsByTagName('img')[0]` or simpler: `tags[i].querySelector('img')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move 'relatively' from each link to its child image so you insure each time you are pointing to the corresponding one like that:

```
(function () {

    var tags = document.getElementsByClassName('item');

    for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; ++i) {
        var img = tags[i].children[0];
        console.log(img);
        var width = img.naturalWidth;
        var height = img.naturalHeight;
        tags[i].style.paddingBottom = (100 * (height / width)) + '%';
    }

}());
```

here is a jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/3k5w0qv0/

Answer (score 0):

The following bit should work to get every image's dimensions individually. I've also added the `load` event listener to be sure it gets the right height and widths.

```
(function () {

    var tags = document.getElementsByClassName('item');

    for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; ++i) {
        var img = tags[i].querySelector('img');
        var src = img ? img.src || false;
        if(src){
            img = document.createElement('img');
            img.addEventListener('load', function(){
                tags[i].style.paddingBottom = (100 * (this.height / this.width)) + '%';
            }, false);
            img.src = src;
        }
    }

}());
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to apply this based on the *img* within each *a* element with a class of *item*, so you might try:

```
 (function () {

    var tags = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
    var img, width, height, tag;

    for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; ++i) {
      tag = tags[i];
      img = tag.querySelector('img'); 
      tag.style.paddingBottom = (100 * (img.naturalHeight / img.naturalWidth)) + '%';
    }
}());
```